# Debugging React code in VSCode when running Playwright tests

Tags: reactjs, playwright

Even if I run both my React (next.js) application and Playwright tests from VSCode, I am unable to debug code running in the browser. Is there any way to achieve this?

I think the problem is that when debugging a React app, VSCode launches it's own browser and hooks up to the remote debugging of that instance but Playwright creates a new browser for each test.

It looks like there may be ways of enabling remote debugging in the browser launched by Playwright or having Playwright connect to an existing browser instead of launching it's own but it's not clear to me which approach, if any, I should be attempting.